# Airflow BashOperator bash command permission denied

Tags: airflow, permission-denied

I'm moving some Airflow DAGs to another Airflow server. The DAGs were running properly before the migration, but now they get "Permission denied" error.

Here is the DAGs logs

```
*** Reading local file: /data/logs_dags_production/dag_id=Fraud_Report/run_id=manual__2022-08-01T13:18:33.188427+00:00/task_id=excel_mail_kapanis/attempt=8.log
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {taskinstance.py:1159} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Fraud_Report.excel_mail_kapanis manual__2022-08-01T13:18:33.188427+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {taskinstance.py:1159} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Fraud_Report.excel_mail_kapanis manual__2022-08-01T13:18:33.188427+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {taskinstance.py:1356} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {taskinstance.py:1357} INFO - Starting attempt 8 of 8
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {taskinstance.py:1358} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {taskinstance.py:1377} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): excel_mail_kapanis> on 2022-08-01 13:18:33.188427+00:00
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 700284 to run task
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'Fraud_Report', 'excel_mail_kapanis', 'manual__2022-08-01T13:18:33.188427+00:00', '--job-id', '51885', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/fraud_reports.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp27idqlsl', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpbitmkjnk']
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 51885: Subtask excel_mail_kapanis
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {task_command.py:370} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: Fraud_Report.excel_mail_kapanis manual__2022-08-01T13:18:33.188427+00:00 [running]> on host AXAIRFLOW01
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/cmhrbskn/airflow_axa/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py:518: SAWarning: Coercing Subquery object into a select() for use in IN(); please pass a select() construct explicitly
  util.warn(

[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {taskinstance.py:1569} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=Fraud_Report
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=excel_mail_kapanis
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-08-01T13:18:33.188427+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=8
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-08-01T13:18:33.188427+00:00
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {subprocess.py:62} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', '/data/airflow_projects/fraud_report/excel_mail_kapanis.sh ']
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {subprocess.py:85} INFO - Output:
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - bash: /data/airflow_projects/fraud_report/excel_mail_kapanis.sh: Permission denied
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {subprocess.py:96} INFO - Command exited with return code 126
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {taskinstance.py:1889} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cmhrbskn/airflow_axa/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 194, in execute
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 126.
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {taskinstance.py:1395} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=Fraud_Report, task_id=excel_mail_kapanis, execution_date=20220801T131833, start_date=20220802T075230, end_date=20220802T075230
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {standard_task_runner.py:92} ERROR - Failed to execute job 51885 for task excel_mail_kapanis (Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 126.; 700284)
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-08-02, 13:52:30 +03] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

This is the excel_mail_kapanis.sh

```
#!/bin/bash



projdir="/data/airflow_projects/fraud_report"
/home/cmhrbskn/airflow_axa/bin/python $projdir"excel_report_kapanis.py"


bugun=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
fn=$(date +%d%m%Y)

myd=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

pdir="/data/airflow_projects/fraud_report/reports/"
#myfile=$pdir"report_$fn.csv"
myfile=$pdir"report_kapanis_$fn.xlsx"


if [ -f "$myfile" ] && [ -s "$myfile" ]; 
then
        echo "Dosya var $myfile"
    printf "Dosyayi ekte gorebilirsiniz.\n\nBu bir otomatik emaildir" | mutt -a $myfile -s "Airflow Kapanış tarihine göre aylık hasar ve fraud raporu - Dosya Gunu $bugun"  -- $EMAIL
else
    echo "Dosya yok email at bulunamadi"
    printf "Dosya bulunamadi $myfile\n\nBu bir otomatik emaildir" | mutt -s "Airflow Kapanış tarihine göre aylık hasar ve fraud raporu - Dosya Gunu $bugun DOSYA YOK"  -- $EMAIL2
fi
```

I removed the mails to prevent privacy violation.

I have tried chmod 777 but that did not work as well.